# Unable to read 25mb image using ImageIO.read(file)

Tags: java, image, heap-memory

While I am reading a 25 MB file it's throwing an Java heap space. It can read 20 MB file but it's unable to read 25 MB file.

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(bean.getFile());
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(is);
```

Comment: try to increase the heap size

Comment: Maybe this article would help you someway.. http://worksheetsoftware.com/index.php/software/blog/29-effective-handling-of-big-images-in-java

Comment: Try using `FileInputStream` instead of `ByteArrayInputStream`

Comment: the input file is byte[] .

Comment: using sts 3.8.1 with jdk 8

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error-64mb-heap

Comment: Do you get an exception then?

Comment: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at java.awt.image.DataBufferByte.<init>(DataBufferByte.java:92)
 at java.awt.image.ComponentSampleModel.createDataBuffer(ComponentSampleModel.java:445)
 at java.awt.image.Raster.createWritableRaster(Raster.java:941)
 at javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier.createBufferedImage(ImageTypeSpecifier.java:1074)
 at javax.imageio.ImageReader.getDestination(ImageReader.java:2892)
 at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readInternal(JPEGImageReader.java:1071)
 at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.read(JPEGImageReader.jav

Comment: Ignore the file size for the moment, how big are the two files in pixels and bit depth (number of possible colors)? Given the clever nature of image compression algorithms, an image file size says little about how big it will be once loaded.